# Android Firebase get all user Info problem

Tags: java, android, firebase

I would like to list the users who registered to the system.

**MainPage:**

```
    List<User> users;
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    User user = postSnapShot.getValue(User.class);
                    users.add(user);
                    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("selam", "onCancelled: " + databaseError );
        }
    });
```

**User Java Class**

```
public class User {


private String email ="";
private String nickname="";
private String status="";
private String uid="";


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getNickname() {
    return nickname;
}

public void setNickname(String nickname) {
    this.nickname = nickname;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}
```

**İmages**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the issue exactly? are you getting wrong output? Are you getting error? Please try to pin point the location of the problem and be more specific about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You get that `NullPointerException` because you haven't initialized your `users` list. To solve this, please use the following code:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists())
        {
            List<User> users = new ArrayList<>(); //Initialize the list
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                User user = postSnapShot.child("userInfo").getValue(User.class);
                users.add(user);

            }
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e("selam", "onCancelled: " + databaseError );
    }
});
```

Please also note, that I moved `customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`, outside the for loop and I have also added `.child("userInfo")` call because there is an extra level in your database tree.

Comment: Hi Enivicivokkey! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?